# Empty Media Query Needed?

Tags: css, media-queries

A developer that we hired has left this in the CSS sheet that he created:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:35em){}
```

It looks to me like it is unnecessary, because nothing is being called to happen. My question is this: can the above entire line of code be deleted?

Also, is there any reason that this may have been left in the CSS sheet? Merci,
Pierre

Comment: That mediaquery has no rule inside so it can be safely removed.
The reason should be asked to your developer. Maybe he was thinking to create some specific style for wider viewports.

Comment: This question is just bait for free rep so I'm only commenting: Yes, you can remove it. Empty media queries don't do anything. Only keep it in if you think you'll need it in the future

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm unsure as to why this has been determined to be "bait," but I do appreciate that answer. I'm not even sure what "free rep" is, as I am new to this website and to working on our website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries left blank - could this cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361700/media-queries-left-blank-could-this-cause-problems)