# Media Queries left blank - could this cause problems?

Tags: css, media-queries

Im curious about leaving the @media definitions empty in my stylesheet and if this could cause some problems rendering the page?

I only want to include those queries for presentation - to show them, that it's possible to go responsive with the queries enabled.

here is my css:

```
/*************************************************************************************************/
/* Media Queries - Responsive Layout Definitionen */
/*************************************************************************************************/

/* Smartphones (Portrait und Landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (Portrait und Landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops und Laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Große Screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
/*************************************************************************************************/
/* ==================== */
/*************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Nothing right?

Comment: yeh, nothing happened - but since I'm totally new to media-queries, I wanted some professional thoughts about this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty `@media` rules have no effect on page rendering or stylesheet parsing. Just make sure you open and close them properly.

If you need the details, the relevant portions of the grammar can be found in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-media). But in a nutshell, a `@media` rule may have zero or more rules nested within, which means it may be empty with no issues.

Comment: thank you very much BoltClock ;)
May I ask you another thing?

I tested the queries with a black background-color - but nothing happened...do I need to add some <meta> before? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @daftpanda: What do you mean? If you mean you simply put `background-color: black` inside, that's not correct. You need to have a selector, just like any other CSS style rule.

Comment: I added a body { background-color: #000;} definition to one of the media-queries, resized the browser window but nothing happened - it just didn't work...what is wrong?

Comment: yeh Mador, I did this - but nothing happened :(

Comment: @daftpanda: I believe resizing the browser window only works with width/height and not device-width/device-height.

Comment: will try this out and give you feedback then ;)